# How to sum interest rate curves in QuantLib

Tags: interest-rates, programming, yield-curve, quantlib

C++ code taken from [**`Bonds.cpp`**](http://quantlib.org/reference/_bonds_8cpp-example.html) and slightly amended:

```
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace QuantLib;

int main(int, char* []) {

    try {

        // Just a couple of parameters

        Calendar calendar = TARGET();
        Date settlementDate(18, September, 2008);
        settlementDate = calendar.adjust(settlementDate);
        Integer fixingDays = 3;
        Natural settlementDays = 3;
        Date todaysDate = calendar.advance(settlementDate, -fixingDays, Days);
        Settings::instance().evaluationDate() = todaysDate;

        /* Now let's introduce two curves: the first one is a swap curve built from 
        deposits and IRS, the second one is a credit spread curve which should be 
        added to the former one to get a proper yield curve */

        // Swap curve

        DayCounter termStructureDayCounter = ActualActual(ActualActual::ISDA);
        double tolerance = 1.0e-5;

        // Deposits

        Rate d1wQuote = 0.043375;
        Rate d1mQuote = 0.031875;
        Rate d3mQuote = 0.0320375;
        Rate d6mQuote = 0.03385;
        Rate d9mQuote = 0.0338125;
        Rate d1yQuote = 0.0335125;

        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d1wRate(new SimpleQuote(d1wQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d1mRate(new SimpleQuote(d1mQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d3mRate(new SimpleQuote(d3mQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d6mRate(new SimpleQuote(d6mQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d9mRate(new SimpleQuote(d9mQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d1yRate(new SimpleQuote(d1yQuote));

        // IRS

        Rate s2yQuote = 0.0295;
        Rate s3yQuote = 0.0323;
        Rate s5yQuote = 0.0359;
        Rate s10yQuote = 0.0412;
        Rate s15yQuote = 0.0433;

        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> s2yRate(new SimpleQuote(s2yQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> s3yRate(new SimpleQuote(s3yQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> s5yRate(new SimpleQuote(s5yQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> s10yRate(new SimpleQuote(s10yQuote));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> s15yRate(new SimpleQuote(s15yQuote));

        // Rate Helper

        // Deposits
        DayCounter depositDayCounter = Actual360();

        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> d1w(new DepositRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d1wRate),
                1*Weeks, fixingDays,
                calendar, ModifiedFollowing,
                true, depositDayCounter));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> d1m(new DepositRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d1mRate),
                1*Months, fixingDays,
                calendar, ModifiedFollowing,
                true, depositDayCounter));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> d3m(new DepositRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d3mRate),
                3*Months, fixingDays,
                calendar, ModifiedFollowing,
                true, depositDayCounter));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> d6m(new DepositRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d6mRate),
                6*Months, fixingDays,
                calendar, ModifiedFollowing,
                true, depositDayCounter));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> d9m(new DepositRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d9mRate),
                9*Months, fixingDays,
                calendar, ModifiedFollowing,
                true, depositDayCounter));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> d1y(new DepositRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d1yRate),
                1*Years, fixingDays,
                calendar, ModifiedFollowing,
                true, depositDayCounter));

        // Setup IRS
        Frequency swFixedLegFrequency = Annual;
        BusinessDayConvention swFixedLegConvention = Unadjusted;
        DayCounter swFixedLegDayCounter = Thirty360(Thirty360::European);
        boost::shared_ptr<IborIndex> swFloatingLegIndex(new Euribor6M);

        const Period forwardStart(1*Days);

        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> s2y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(s2yRate), 2*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> s3y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(s3yRate), 3*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> s5y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(s5yRate), 5*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> s10y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(s10yRate), 10*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> s15y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(s15yRate), 15*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));


        // A depo-swap curve
        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> > depoSwapInstruments;
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(d1w);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(d1m);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(d3m);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(d6m);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(d9m);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(d1y);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(s2y);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(s3y);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(s5y);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(s10y);
        depoSwapInstruments.push_back(s15y);
        boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure> depoSwapTermStructure(
                new PiecewiseYieldCurve<Discount,LogLinear>(
                        settlementDate, depoSwapInstruments,
                        termStructureDayCounter,
                        tolerance));

        return 0;

    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "unknown error" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If I'm not wrong, so far we've been obtaining a kind of risk free discount curve.

Now let me to introduce an additional credit spread curve in the form of an object handled by `RateHelper` (kinda snippet to be inserted after the depo-swap curve of the code above):

```
        ...
        Rate d1ySpread = 0.013;
        Rate d2ySpread = 0.011;
        Rate d3ySpread = 0.022;
        Rate d6ySpread = 0.0238;
        Rate d9ySpread = 0.0238;
        Rate d10ySpread = 0.0239;

        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d1ySpreadRate(new SimpleQuote(d1ySpread));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d2ySpreadRate(new SimpleQuote(d2ySpread));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d3ySpreadRate(new SimpleQuote(d3ySpread));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d6ySpreadRate(new SimpleQuote(d6ySpread));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d9ySpreadRate(new SimpleQuote(d9ySpread));
        boost::shared_ptr<Quote> d10ySpreadRate(new SimpleQuote(d10ySpread));

        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> credit1y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d1ySpreadRate), 1*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> credit2y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d2ySpreadRate), 2*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> credit3y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d3ySpreadRate), 3*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> credit6y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d6ySpreadRate), 6*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> credit9y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d9ySpreadRate), 9*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));
        boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> credit10y(new SwapRateHelper(
                Handle<Quote>(d10ySpreadRate), 10*Years,
                calendar, swFixedLegFrequency,
                swFixedLegConvention, swFixedLegDayCounter,
                swFloatingLegIndex, Handle<Quote>(),forwardStart));

        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<RateHelper> > creditInstruments;
        creditInstruments.push_back(credit1y);
        creditInstruments.push_back(credit2y);
        creditInstruments.push_back(credit3y);
        creditInstruments.push_back(credit6y);
        creditInstruments.push_back(credit9y);
        creditInstruments.push_back(credit10y);
        boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure> creditTermStructure(
                new PiecewiseYieldCurve<Discount,LogLinear>(
                        settlementDate, creditInstruments,
                        termStructureDayCounter,
                        tolerance));
        ...
```

The object `creditTermStructure` could represent, as instance, a CDS spread curve, or such a term structure.

Having both the `depoSwapTermStructure` and the `creditTermStructure` built by the code above, I would like to produce a new object of class `YieldTermStructure` by summing `depoSwapTermStructure` and `creditTermStructure` taking into account the misaligned time knots, that is, the code must sum the rates by the appropriate tenors (1Y depo-swap + 1Y credit spread, 2Y depo-swap + 2Y credit spread... and so on. As of the lacking credit spread maturities, such as 18Y, it should be interpolate known knots).

How is it possible to do such a thing using **QuantLib**?

Comment: What are the spreads you're using for the second curve? You're passing them to SwapRateHelpers, so you're using them as swap rates; that is, you'll build a curve on which swaps paying those (fixed) rates are priced at par.  Is this correct?

Comment: Hi, Luigi. Actually the one you've mentioned above is a clarification which I didn't want to involve in this issue. You may consider the snippet just an attempt to build a generic rate curve, regardless of what instruments it comes from. As instance, what if they were CDS spreads instead of swap rates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no class at this time to add two curves as you want, but it won't be much difficult to write it.

The closest you'll get in the library is the `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` class, that shows the general idea: it inherits from `YieldTermStructure` (by way of `ZeroYieldStructure`) takes a `YieldTermStructure` and a spread (constant, in this case) and override its own methods so that they return the sum of the two: for instance,

```
Rate ZeroSpreadedTermStructure::forwardImpl(Time t) const {
    return originalCurve_->forwardRate(t, t, comp_, freq_, true)
        + spread_->value();
}
```

In your case, you'll have to write a similar class that takes two `Handle`s to `YieldTermStructure` instead.  Somewhat surprisingly, this will make your job easier.  You can still take `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` as a model for other tasks such as registering with the needed observers, but all you have to do in this case is inherit from `YieldTermStructure` directly and override the single `discountImpl` method:

```
DiscountFactor YourClass::discountImpl(Time t) const {
    return baseCurve_->discount(t, true)
         * spreadCurve_->discount(t, true);
}
```

since the sum of the rates implies the product of the corresponding discount factors.

If you need more information, a description of the `YieldTermStructure` hierarchy and the methods it implements (which is kind of longish to include here) is available at http://implementingquantlib.blogspot.com/2013/09/chapter-3-part-2-of-n-yield-term.html and later posts.

And of course, once you have your curve working, you're welcome to contribute it to QuantLib. The easier way would be to get a GitHub account and follow the instructions in the readme at https://github.com/lballabio/quantlib.

Comment: One question on the implementation of `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure`: in the declaration of `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure::forwardImpl` I see the comment `/* This method must disappear should the spread become a curve */`. Besides, `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure` inherits `ZeroYieldStructure` which inherits `YieldTermStructure` which only requires to implement `discountImpl`, while `forwardImpl` is required for `ForwardRateStructure`, which is not a base class. So why is `forwardImpl` implemented in `ZeroSpreadedTermStructure`? And what is the meaning of the comment I reported above?

Comment: I think it's a leftover from a previous implementation.  The idea was that of a shortcut to gain some performance; a constant spread over zero rates gives an equal constant spread on forwards, so we coded it directly instead of relying on the default implementation (which performed a numerical differentiation). But you're right, it's not used anymore and should disappear.

Comment: As for the comment: if the spread were time-dependent, the shortcut would no longer apply.